# number of games to be played until a set score can be reached

Tags: probability, statistics

In this situation, I am to play a game, where i have a 30% win chance. If I win, I gain one point, and if I lose, I lose one point. Points cannot go below zero, and I am allowed to play until I get 10 points. How would I calculate the number of games that I would likely need to play until I can reach 10 points?

Comment: There are many ways to reach 10 points with different number of games.

Comment: I realize, and I was thinking how i'd figure out an overall statistical expectation, since it doesn't seem too logical to calculate it by hand (e.g. adding all possible 10H + 9H 2Ts + 8H 3Ts.. etc), if that was possible

Comment: How many points do you have to start with?

Comment: @BarryCipra 0! I am reading the answers that the two people have provided, but am having a hard time. Will probably have to work at it myself for a long while it seems :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=10$, we have $E(10) = 0$

For $0 < n < 10$, we have $E(n) = 1 + .3E(n+1) + .7E(n-1)$

For $n=0$, we have $E(0) = 1 + .3E(1) + .7E(0)$

Over $0 \leq n \leq 10$, it comes out to:

$$E(n) = \dfrac{5 n}{2} - \frac{5}{8} 3^{-n} 7^{n + 1} + \frac{9874823915}{472392}$$

For $n=0$, that's $E(0) = \dfrac{1234094650}{59049} \approx 20899.5$

Comment: thanks for the answer! i really needed the numbers quick, aside from my willingness to work on the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

For $0\le n\le 10$, let $f(n)$ denote the *expected* number of games it takes until you reach $10$ for the first time.

- Clearly, $f(10)=0$.
- For $0<n<10$, we have $f(n)=1+\frac3{10}f(n+1)+\frac7{10}f(n-1).$
- Finally, $f(0)=1+\frac3{10}f(1)+\frac7{10}f(0).$

That's 11 linear equations in 11 unknowns and can be solved.

Comment: whew. thanks, while this looks really puzzling to me at the moment, i'll work my way toward it as i linger on this problem for a few days